# Spawn of a multiprocess.Process is not filling Queue correctly in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am currently writing a connection manager for a stress test in Python it seems my queue is never filling up.  This pseudoesque-code will explain it better than I can:

```
def wget(processQueue)
    currProcess = subprocess.Popen(./wget)
    processQueue.put(currProcess)

def connection(processQueue)
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=wget, args=(processQueue,))
    process.start()

processQueue = Queue.Queue()
newConnection = multiprocessing.Process(target=connection, args=(processQueue,))
newConnection.start()
processQueue.qsize() # This is 0
```

Can anyway explain why my queue has a size of 0?

Comment: Also, I failed to realize the difference between Queue.Queue and multiprocessing.Queue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `processQueue.qsize`, note that the docs say :

```
Definition: processQueue.qsize(self)
Docstring:
    Return the approximate size of the queue (not reliable!).
```

so you shouldn't rely on `qsize` to tell you if the queue is empty.

Also, since you may be reaching the line `processQueue.qsize` *before* the `processQueue.put` is called, the queue may indeed be empty at that moment but not empty forever.

Comment: what happens if I have a lot of arguments, ex: args=(username, password, url, processQueue)... does this still apply?